# Gathering desired data in array with loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two different arrays, first one is types_array and second one is result_array. I want to collect data from result_array as per type in types_array and put into new array. 
It is only matching the first record of index in types_array not others. I am adding the arrays directly as I am getting in my result so you can have better understanding.

Types Array

```
Array          
(
 [0] => class
 [1] => late_fine
 [2] => exam_fees
)
```

Result Array

```
Array          
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [unit_name] => class 1
        [price] => 10
        [type] => class
    )

  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [unit_name] => class 1
        [price] => 10
        [type] => class
    )

  [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [unit_name] => late fine
        [price] => 50
        [type] => late_fine
    )

  [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [unit_name] => late fine
        [price] => 40
        [type] => late_fine
    )
 )
```

Result I am getting

```
  Array      
  (
    [class] => Array
    (
        [name] => class 1
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 10
    )
 )
```

Result I am expecting

```
  Array       
  (
    [class] => Array
    (
        [name] => class 1
        ['price'] => 20

    )

    [late_fine] => Array
    (
        [name] => late fine
        ['price'] => 100

    )

 )
```

My Code

```
$i=0;
$x=0;
$types_array = array_values(student_payment_types());

while($x < count($types_array)){

    while($i < count($result_array)){

        if( $types_array[$x] == $result_array[$i]->type ){

            $data_array[$types_array[$x]]['name'] = $result_array[$i]->unit_name;
            $data_array[$types_array[$x]][] += (int)$result_array[$i]->price;

        }

        $i++;
    }

    unset($types_array[$x]);
    array_values($types);

    $x++;
}
```

Comment: Please can you label the arrays with names that match the code variables just so we know for sure what is what here

Comment: You might also like to review the use of `foreach` as a looping mechanism

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly I have named the arrays, please guide me where I am wrong

Comment: Please explain how you get from the input arrays to the last one.  My guess, Class = 10 + 10 = 20.  late_fine = 50 + 40 == 100?!?   exam_fees, no  data so nothing.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I got it, I was doing a silly mistake, I need to set $i back to zero when I come out of inner loop.

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly and Nick3500.